# Shortest distance between two shapes

Tags: geometry, algorithms, optimization

This is the scenario of my problem. I have an image of **two objects** ( of **arbitrary shape**, **not convex**, **not touching or crossing each other**, **kept a few space apart**).

And I am supposed to **find the shortest distance between these two shapes**.

First thing that came to my mind was to **use bruteforce methods**, ie find all the elements of shape A's perimeter (Let it be set X) and same for B's perimeter (Let it be Y ). Then find distance between all possible combinations ( excluding repetitions) of elements of X and Y and take the minimum value in it.

But I am sure **it will take a lot of time**.

**`Is there any other better way to do this ?`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find lots of literature via the key phrase *collision detection*. For example,
the 2004 paper,
"Efficient Collision Detection between 2D Polygons" ([PDF download link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160804083453/http://iason.zcu.cz:80/wscg2004/Papers_2004_Full/B83.pdf)),
or another 2004 paper, "Kinetic collision detection for two simple polygons" ([author link](http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/%7Ejeffe/pubs/cdsimple.html)).
I even ran across a recent patented(!) algorithm:
"Collision detection of concave bodies using art gallery problem and cube maps,"
2010
([patent link](http://www.google.com/patents?hl=en&lr=&vid=USPAT7737997&id=vxDVAAAAEBAJ&oi=fnd&printsec=abstract#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

And here is some older literature:
"Efficient distance computation between non-convex objects,"
1994 ([IEEE link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/351059)).
From any of these papers, you could search forward in time via Google Scholar.

Comment: +1 - I didn't know its name is Collision detection. Thank you. I will have a look at the links.